# How to remove unknown index elements from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form and I am using AJAX when user clicks on submit button. In AJAX related PHP page I have used **$_POST** (with out specifying the related values) .

This is working fine. But now I have implemented one bootstrap dialog box popup on that form. Now from my post method I am getting values from the dialog box also. This leads me into problem.The values are coming from bootstrap modal are dynamic values. Here is my post array.

```
Array(
[start_val] => 0
[accept-82RUFA55] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)

[hidden_order_id244] => 82RUFA55
[asin244] => 331800000221
[accept-82RUFA54] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)

[hidden_order_id239] => 82RUFA54
[asin239] => 331800000221
[accept-82RUFA53] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)
```

)

But my desired Array should be like below.

```
Array
(
[start_val] => 0
[accept-82RUFA55] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)
[accept-82RUFA54] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)
[accept-82RUFA53] => Array
(
    [0] => 4046228181417
    [1] => 4046228181448
    [2] => 331800000221
)

)
```

In array elements to **hidden_order_id** and **asin** I am concatenating the unique id.

This id is dynamic one. So I want to delete those elements from Array. 
So how to remove those values from my array ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _“Now from my post method I am getting values from the dialog box also. This leads me into problem.”_ - why/how? If you do not _want_ to get values from the modal - then why did you integrate it into the form in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get keys to delete by preg_grep on keys of input array

```
$keys = preg_grep('~^(asin\d+|hidden_order_id\d+)~', array_keys($input));
foreach($keys as $key) {
   unset($input[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @splash58. This is working like charm. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $max_dynamic_id; $i++) { 
    unset($arr['hidden_order_id' . $i]);
    unset($arr['asin' . $i]);
}
```

Please, let me know if this doesn't suit your case with the reason and I will modify the answer.